# How to set .bmp image to ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a `list` of `ImageView`s, which download the images from the net.
I downloaded the images from server and it displays in `ImageView`, but `.bmp` images don't show in `ImageView`.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly check the following code:

```
RelativeLayout relLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    URL centreImageURL = new URL(imageUrl);
                    URLConnection conn = centreImageURL.openConnection();
                    conn.connect();
                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
// 110 , 110 are the bitmap width & height
                    Bitmap tempBitmapImg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 110, 110,
                            true);
                    centreImgView.setImageBitmap(tempBitmapImg);

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp5 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    lp5.setMargins((screenWidth / 2) - 50,
                            (screenHeight / 2) - 105, 0, 0);

                    relLayout.addView(centreImgView, lp5);
setContentView(relLayout);
```

Kindly revert for any clarifications

Answer (score 0):

This is the method you just need to pass the url of your image that you need to download.

This method on completion will return Drawable that you can directly set to a ImageView

```
Drawable drawable_from_url(String url, String src_name) throws java.net.MalformedURLException, java.io.IOException 
{
    return Drawable.createFromStream(((java.io.InputStream)new java.net.URL(url).getContent()), src_name);
}
```

Use it as below

```
ImageView mImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.MyImageView);
mImage.setImageDrawable(drawable_from_url("http://your/image/url/here", "src"));
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: moreover if you are implementing this for a ListView with a list of images that need to be fetched from net and then need to be displayed in the List. use threading to download images and then use Handler class to implement Visual Changes in the List after ensuring that images once fetched should not be feteched again. and getView Method of your List need to be light else the scrolling will be very slow and jerky